# Issue in test class for a trigger

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

I am writing a test class for a trigger and in the trigger and the helper class the code is to generate contract numbers according to the record types.

```apex
@isTest
public class testGenerateGrantContractNumber {
    @isTest static void testGrantContractNumbers(){
        Account acc1=new Account();
        acc1.Name='Test acc';
        insert acc1;
        
        RecordType rt =[select id,DeveloperName from RecordType where sObjectType='Contract' AND DeveloperName ='DYS Contracts' limit 1];      
        Contract c=new Contract();  
        c.RecordTypeId=rt.id;
        c.AccountId=acc1.Id;
        System.debug('c.AccountId'+ c.AccountId);
        c.StartDate=Date.Parse('02/14/2022');
        c.Status='Draft';
        c.ContractTerm=15;
        insert c;
        
        RecordType rtOpp =[select id,DeveloperName from RecordType where sObjectType='Opportunity' AND DeveloperName ='DYS Contracts' limit 1];
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Name = 'OppName';
        opp.AccountId = acc1.Id;
        opp.StageName = 'Pre-Award';
        Opp.CloseDate = Date.Parse('02/14/2022');
        opp.RecordTypeId = rtOpp.Id;
        Insert opp;
        
        RecordType rt1 =[select id,DeveloperName from RecordType where sObjectType='Grant_Contract__c' AND DeveloperName='WTFP_General' limit 1];
        Grant_Contract__c gc=new Grant_Contract__c();  
        gc.RecordTypeId=rt1.Id;
        gc.Grant_Name__c = Opp.Id;
        gc.Name='Test Feb-1';
        gc.Master_Contract__c=c.Id;    
        gc.Program_or_Professional_Service__c='Program';
        gc.Stage__c ='In Progress';
        insert gc;

        test.startTest();
        String WtfpGenfirst='23000021';        
        //String substring1=gc.Name.left(3);
        //system.assertNotEquals(null,gc);
        System.assertEquals(gc.Name,WtfpGenfirst);   
        test.stopTest();
    }
```

Here the account grant and contract are fields required while inserting grant contract.

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY

While running the test class I am getting this error.
Trigger should work only on after insert.

Comment: Originally from @Tejaswini who does not yet have enough rep to comment: "Can you please tell which line of the above insert is failing? Also check the access to the record type you are using in the test class. Instead of querying `recordtype` object, you can get record type id using this SObject function: `String rt1 =Schema.SObjectType.Contract.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('WTFP General').getRecordTypeId();`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your Trigger for Grant_Contract__c is writing a field but does not have permissions. Make sure all your field you are setting in your trigger have write permissions. Additionally you could share your trigger logic as well

Comment: I have fixed this issue. Missed initializing a field value while writing the trigger test class.